# Why does using Linq with a list and Table entity from DataContext throw a "Local Sequence" exception?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datacontext

I am using Linq in a .net C# application. I am trying to retrieve results from a Table in my DataContext based on a join with a local list of objects.

**I am running into the following error message:**

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query
> operators except the Contains operator.

**Here is a code snippet illustrating the issue:**

```
List<Employees> employees;

using (DataContext context = MyApp.Instance)
{
    var payrolls = context.Payrolls.Where(
        o => employees.Any(e => o.EmpID == e.EmpID && e.BudgetID == o.BudgetID))
    .ToList();
}
```

**I also tried:**

```
payrolls = (from LT in context.Payrolls
      from LR in employees
      where LT.EmpID == LR.EmpID &&
             && LT.BUDGETID == LR.BudgetID
      select LT).ToList();
```

I get the same error.

If I reverse the order and do: employees.Where() first, this works fine.

I need to be able to return the list of Payroll records that match up against the collection of Employee.

How do I get this to work using Linq?

Comment: you need to user inner join

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: @Izikon - Can you pls provide quick example?

Comment: look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45983443-19a6-44e8-93f9-c91eb28da48b/linq-to-sql-join-on-two-columns?forum=aspadoentitylinq